# What happen when closing Ionic Firestore app with offline persistance?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire

If I have Ionic 4 app that uses the firebase JS SDK (AngurlarFire5) with firestore's offline persistence enabled, what would happen if there are pending requests and the app get closed either by sending it to background or completely closing it? Would it sync when re-opening the app or the pending requests/data will be lost?

Answer (score 1):

The way offline persistence works on *all platforms* is like this.  When data is written, the write is committed to local storage before it's synchronized to the server.  Eventually, when the app is running and it's able to connecto to Firestore again, the writes will be synchronized.  Killing the app doesn't change this behavior.  It just delays the sync until the app is launched again and is able to connect.

Comment: As far as I understand, firebase JS SDK uses indexedDB for data persistence. So, if deploying to iOS, which uses WKWebview, does this mean the lifetime of the indexedDB is not limited to the time when killing the app?

Comment: I don't do iOS development, but I don't think it matters.  I suggest simply trying it for yourself in a test app to see how it works.